# How do I host a webapp using php and mongodb on heroku?

Tags: php, mongodb, heroku

This is how I am attempting to connect to the database on heroku:

```
//db.php
$config = array( 
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'connection_string'=> sprintf('mongodb://%s:%d','EXAMPLE.herokuapp.com','27017')    
    );
$connection = new \MongoClient($config['connection_string']);
```

When I pushed to the repo, and go to the app URL the follow error message is shown:
Failed to connect to: EXAMPLE.herokuapp.com:27017 Connection refused in db.php.

How should I format the connection_string so that it will not give the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no locally running MongoDB available on Heroku.

You need to use one of the add-ons at https://addons.heroku.com/#data-stores such as MongoLab.

When you run

```
$ heroku addons:add mongolab
```

it's provisioned for you, and there will be a config variable in the environment with the connection information:

```
$ heroku config | grep MONGOLAB_URI
MONGOLAB_URI => mongodb://heroku_app1234:random_password@ds029017.mongolab.com:29017/heroku_app1234
```

You can just read that from `$_ENV['MONGOLAB_URI']`, or using `getenv('MONGOLAB_URI')`:

```
$connection = new \MongoClient(getenv('MONGOLAB_URI'));
```

Comment: Then would you please accept and upvote the answer? That's how Stack Overflow works...